# No longer able to boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, bios, canonical

My computer runs Ubuntu and no longer boots. I’ve attached the log from `boot-repair` But don’t know how to fix the problem:

```
boot-repair-4ppa130                                              [20210916_0927]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32816 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
No EFI in dmseg.
SecureBoot enabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002
Boot0000* UEFI Lexar USB Flash Drive AACI4MFFHNW7BYBZ   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4ee5b1,0x800,0x1dd5800)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1a3d2b6c-f752-48e6-9101-5c8c0fd603ba,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
This session has been detected as 'live' because df -Th / contains overlay



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sdb: 14.94 GiB, 16018046976 bytes, 31285248 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x004ee5b1
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 31285247 31283200 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:-512.00B:scsi:512:512:unknown:ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1:;
sdb:16.0GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Lexar USB Flash Drive:;
1:1049kB:16.0GB:16.0GB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat     2CAF-E43E                            004ee5b1-01                          UBUNTU 20_0 

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                  Avail Use% Mounted on
sdb1                12G  19% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sdb1              ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sda



=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

ERROR: asr: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709419520
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709545472
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550080
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073708468224
ERROR: jmicron: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: lsi: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: nvidia: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550080
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438913024
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438920192
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438927360
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438934528
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: via: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: asr: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709419520
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709545472
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550080
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073708468224
ERROR: jmicron: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: lsi: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: nvidia: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550080
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438913024
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438920192
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438927360
ERROR: pdc: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 137438934528
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
ERROR: via: seeking device "/dev/sda" to 18446744073709550592
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[85462]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 17618: /bin/bash

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________
```

The default repair with `boot-repair` did not resolve the problem.

Comment: The ERROR is unreadable please format it so it can be.

Comment: From the looks of it, you either have a dead storage device or managed to completely empty it out. What were you doing before the computer failed to boot? Were there any software updates? Is the computer running 20.04 like the Live USB? 

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you should format UEFI partition as `fat32` and Ubuntu partition as `ext4`.